# How to config nginx to only return the response from the proxy in case the content-type is correct?

Tags: nginx, openresty

```
location / {
    proxy_pass       http://image_server:8000;
}
```

In normal case, the proxy server will return image/png. But in other cases (for example out of bandwidth), it will throw application/json (with 200 HTTP) instead of images.
So how to only accept images from the proxy, I want to show a 500 error page instead of it returning application/json from the proxy

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done with 'legacy' nginx, do you need an openresty/lua-ngx-module LUA solution?

Comment: I'm using openresty, openresty solution is welcome too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An openresty/lua-ngx-module solution:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass       http://image_server:8000;
    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        if string.find( ngx.header.content_type, "json" ) then
            ngx.exit(500)
        end
    }
}
```

or

```
location / {
    proxy_pass       http://image_server:8000;
    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        if string.find( ngx.header.content_type, "image/" ) == nil then
            ngx.exit(500)
        end
    }
}
```